# C++ <random> generate in a single line

Tags: c++, random

beginner at C++ here.

I have been generating random numbers in C++ using the following function:

```
double randDouble() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(1.0, 10.0);
    return dist(mt);
}
```

I was wondering why I am unable to do this in say a single line, (using temporary  objects) like so:

```
double randDouble2() {
    return std::uniform_real_distribution<double>{1.0, 10.0}(std::default_random_engine(std::random_device{}()));
}
```

I think I read somewhere it is something to do with the default constructor not being explicit for these classes, but I'm not really sure what to search to find out whether I am correct?

I have also read that this would be bad practice since creating a new `random_device` for every call would be quite expensive, however, I am interested in why the one-liner is not *possible* rather than not *practical* - that is to say I am interested in the *general case* for creating anonymous objects (unsure whether this is the right term).

Comment: If you are re-seeding the Mersenne twister for every number anyway, you might just as well skip it altogether and generate from `std::random_device` directly. You probably want you `mt` to be `static` or `thread_local`.

Comment: The generator (`std::mt19937`) has to be `static` (making a new generator for each new number makes no sense). You can shorten it's construction to `static std::mt19937 mt(std::random_device{}());`. You could make the distribution `static` too. There isn't much else you can do.

Comment: That aside, your seeding is sub-optimal. See e.g. my question [Seed std::mt19937 from std::random\_device](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/109260) for a more thorough attempt.

Comment: The reason it is not possible is `std::uniform_real_distribution`'s `operator()` takes the generator by non-const lvalue reference.  That means it can't bind to the temporary PRNG that you create.  The why of that, besides the fact that can be very inefficient, idk.

Comment: Thanks all. I realise now the error of generating the random device every time. @BaummitAugen thanks for the link - I'll keep that in mind when I move on to "proper" projects.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver - that was the general answer that I was looking for.